# Clean Temporary Files created by Razor Engine in Service

Tags: c#, .net

We have a service which generates some files based razor engine. Overtime, there are lots of temporary files generated. Based on some search, we need to Unload the new AppDomain to start the clean of the temporary file.

However, since in the service, there are several places we used Razor Engine, and we do not want to change that part of the code at all.

Is there any other way to do the clean up?

Here is what we think:

In our case, the temporary folder is: C:\Users{ServiceUserName}\AppData\Local*, looks like we can get the Service UserName, then go to this folder and do the clean up.

Is this ok? any possible issues?

Thanks